# How to get all the unique n-long combinations of a set of duplicatable elements?

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinatorics

I have found many solutions giving a collection elements combined in all possible orders but they all use every element just once in every result while I need  them to be treated as reusable.

For example if input elements are {"a", "b", "c"} and the number is 2 the output is to be {"a", "a"}, {"a", "b"}, {"a", "c"}, {"b", "a"}, {"b", "b"},  {"b", "c"}, {"c", "a"}, {"c", "b"}, {"a", "c"}.

Comment: This is called "combinations with replacement", and is mathematically equivalent to the cartesian product of the given set with the set {1,2,3...n}. You generally won't find that in libraries because it's considered too simple to need one. Combinations without replacement as you point out are common in libraries because they are trickier.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you've got N input elements, and you want a K-long combination.

All you need to do is to count in base N, scoped of course, to all numbers that have K digits.

So, lets say N = {n0, n1, ... nN}

You'd start from the number [n0 n0 ... n0], and count all the way up to [nN nN ... nN]

If you'd like help in understanding how to count in another base, you can get that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832822/how-do-you-count-in-another-base)

Each number that you compute maps to one of the K-long combinations that you need.

**I think an example will help**

I'll use your values.
N = {a, b, c}
So we want to count in base 3. 
Since we want 2-long combinations, we only care about 2-digit numbers.
The smallest 2-digit base 3 number is 00, so we start there. By counting in base 3, we get:

```
00
01
02
10
11
12
20
21
22
```

Ok, so now to convert these numbers into a combination.

Remember, our set is {a, b, c}

So whenever we see a 0, it implies 1. Wherever we see 1, it implies 2, and I'm sure you can guess what a 2 implies :)

```
00              aa
01              ab
02              ac
10   0 => a     ba
11   1 => b     bb
12   2 => c     bc
20              ca
21              cb
22              cc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search):

```
class Program
{
    private static string[] letters = {"a", "b", "c"};
    private static void dfs(string accum, int depth)
    {
        if (depth == 0)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(accum);
            return;
        }
        foreach (string c in letters)
            dfs(accum + c, depth - 1);
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        int depth = 2; //Number of letters in each result
        dfs("", depth);
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

Answer (score 1):

Eric Lippert has presented a general-purpose method of generating a cartesian product from any number of sequences [which he blogs about here](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/).

He wrote an extension method that looks like this:

```
public static class Combinations
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        return sequences.Aggregate(
            emptyProduct,
            (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            select accseq.Concat<T>(new[] { item }));
    }
}
```

Given that extension method, the solution to the original problem can be done like this:

```
var items = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };

int numInEachSelection = 2;

var combs = Enumerable.Repeat(items, numInEachSelection).CartesianProduct();

foreach (var comb in combs)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", comb));
```

Note that `combs` is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` - it is a sequence of enumerables each of which is a sequence representing one combination.

If you don't need a general-purpose method like that and you are happy to have each combination in a separate object with properties called `Item1` and `Item2` for the two combined items, the easiest way is this:

```
var items = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };

var combs = from Item1 in items from Item2 in items select new {Item1, Item2};

foreach (var comb in combs)
    Console.WriteLine(comb);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple - you count. If you have 3 elements, as in your example, and want all two-element combinations, you just count from 0 to 8 (3^2 - 1), and treat the result as a base-3 number with your elements as the digits.

If you have 15 elements and want 8-element combinations, you count from 0 to 15^8-1 and treat your result as a base-15 number.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for are permutations not combinations. Unique combinations can be found through tree traversal of k of n elements. If you want n of n elements unique, the answer is 1